# Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I tried to load some scripts into a page using `innerHTML` on a `<div>`. It appears that the script loads into the DOM, but it is never executed (at least in Firefox and Chrome). Is there a way to have scripts execute when inserting them with `innerHTML`?

Sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onload="document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = '<script>alert(\'hi\')<\/script>'">
    Shouldn't an alert saying 'hi' appear?
    <div id="loader"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have to use [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to execute any script code that you've inserted as DOM text.

MooTools will do this for you automatically, and I'm sure jQuery would as well (depending on the version. jQuery version 1.6+ uses `eval`).  This saves a lot of hassle of parsing out `<script>` tags and escaping your content, as well as a bunch of other "gotchas".

Generally if you're going to `eval()` it yourself, you want to create/send the script code without any HTML markup such as `<script>`, as these will not `eval()` properly.

Comment: What I really want to do is to load an external script, not just eval some local script. Adding a script tag with innerHTML is much shorter than creating a script DOM element and adding it to the body, and I am trying to make my code as short as possible. Do you have to create the dom script elements and add them to the dom rather than just using something like innerHTML? Is there a way to do this with document.write from within a function?

Comment: As zombat suggest, use a Javascript framework to load the external script, don't try to reinvent the wheel. JQuery makes this extremely easy, just include JQuery and call: $.getScript(url). You can also provide a callback function that will get executed once the script is loaded.

Comment: Ariel is right.  I appreciate trying to keep your code short, and adding a `<script>` tag with `innerHTML` might be short, but it doesn't work.  It's all just plain text until it gets run through `eval()`.  And sadly, `eval()` doesn't parse HTML tags, so you end up with a chain of problems.

Comment: eval() is not a great solution to any problem.

Comment: I tried eval() myself. It is a horrible idea. You have to eval the whole thing **EACH TIME**. Even if you declare a variable name and value, you have to re-declare/re-eval() it every time afresh to make it work. It's a nightmare of errors.

Comment: @buley Why is it not?

Comment: @Barrosy often but not always "evil" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 135):

Here is a method that recursively replaces all scripts with executable ones:

```
function nodeScriptReplace(node) {
        if ( nodeScriptIs(node) === true ) {
                node.parentNode.replaceChild( nodeScriptClone(node) , node );
        }
        else {
                var i = -1, children = node.childNodes;
                while ( ++i < children.length ) {
                      nodeScriptReplace( children[i] );
                }
        }

        return node;
}
function nodeScriptClone(node){
        var script  = document.createElement("script");
        script.text = node.innerHTML;

        var i = -1, attrs = node.attributes, attr;
        while ( ++i < attrs.length ) {                                    
              script.setAttribute( (attr = attrs[i]).name, attr.value );
        }
        return script;
}

function nodeScriptIs(node) {
        return node.tagName === 'SCRIPT';
}
```

**Example call:**

```
nodeScriptReplace(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
```

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that your answer it's all the way down. IMHO, this is the best solution, this method would even allow you to restrict scripts with specific urls or content.

Comment: what is the purpoes of [0]? can you use nodeScriptReplace(document.getElementById().html);

Comment: @BaoThai Yes. You can.

Comment: Does not seem to help in IWebBrowser2; I can confirm the script tags get recreated with createElement, but I'm still unable to invoke them via InvokeScript().

Comment: @Dave you sure you have the proper attributes on it ? rel='text/javascritp' for instance?

Comment: I get an erro Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined , but I am a beginner. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber there is no promises in this code, so probably not related to this.

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you :)
In case anyone is looking for a more modern version of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69190644/1343851

Answer (score 99):

Here is a very interesting solution to your problem:
http://24ways.org/2005/have-your-dom-and-script-it-too

So use this instead of script tags:

`<img src="empty.gif" onload="alert('test');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />`

Comment: How do you people add the &lt;img src... line to your page code? Do you document.write() it or use document.body.innerHTML+= approach for that? Both are failing for me :(

Comment: Not very practical to write a lot of code inside an `onload` attribute. Also this requires an additional file to exist and to be loaded. [momo's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396/288906) is less of a compromise.

Comment: Two drawbacks: 1. It cannot call any scripts/functions added through the innerHTML(along with this IMG tag) because they dont exist as far as the browser is concerned 2. If part of the inline code before ".removeChild()" throws an exception, the img element will not be removed.

Comment: One quick point. This solution may not give you accurate results, if you are loading larger images above it (since they may take longer to download than your empty gif).

Comment: You could Base64 encode your trigger-image as ``<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">`` (this will not do a network request) Actually... you do NOT need an image, reference a non-existing image and instead of ``onload`` use ``onerror`` (but this will do a network request)

Comment: user447963 & Danny'365CSI'Engelman: This is really brilliant. This is what maybe might be called hacking. Thinking differently to achieve something that would not be possible otherwise. A thing you do not normally think of (although you know of it somewhere in your head).

Comment: Easiest to implement and works in all major browsers (tested in IE, Edge, Opera, Firefox & Chrome latest versions). Thinking outside the box does have it's benefits!

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Oooooor, write something invalid to `src`: will trigger onerror but won't make a network request: `src="?" onerror="alert('Hello');this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"`

Answer (score 53):

I do this every time I want to insert a script tag dynamically:

```
const html =
  `<script>
      alert(' there ! Wanna grab a '); 
  </script>`;

const scriptEl = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
parent.append(scriptEl);
```

Note: this uses ES6.

I've seen a lot of answers use `appendChild` and it works exactly as `append`.

Comment: you can use this nice react component - https://github.com/christo-pr/dangerously-set-html-content

Comment: its a relatively new solution to an old problem :P

Comment: this does not run the script.

Comment: I'm so amazed by you answer. I searched for 5 hours before trying your solution. @TilakMaddy do you know any reason why people don't mention createContextualRange as solution ? is there any browser compatibility issue ?

Comment: It does work as intended. I managed to put all in a single line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Great solution! Small clarification:  `appendChild `and `append` doesn't work exactly the same: `append `accepts text/string while `appendChild` method can only be used to insert Node objects into the DOM. There are certain cases where one or the other is preferred (if you want to enforce using Node objects and avoid string like `<p>` in your code, or if you want to have strings appended). But in most cases you can use either one.

Answer (score 52):

You can create script and then inject the content.

```
var g = document.createElement('script');
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
g.text = "alert(\"hi\");"
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
```

**This works in all browsers :)**

Comment: Unless there aren't any other script elements in the document. Use `document.documentElement` instead.

Comment: Isn't necessary because you are writing a script from another script.

`<script>`
`var g = document.createElement('script');`
`var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; //reference this script`
`g.text = "alert(\"hi\");"`
`s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);`
`</script>`

Comment: Who says it's from another script? You can run JavaScript without `<script>` elements. E.g. `<img onerror="..." src="#">` and `<body onload="...">`. If you want to be technical, this won't work in non-HTML/SVG documents either due to the inexplicit namespacing.

Comment: Facebook uses Pablo's answer in their SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2#loading

Answer (score 31):

I used this code, it is working fine

```
var arr = MyDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')
for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
    eval(arr[n].innerHTML)//run script inside div
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed my problem of adding Disqus Universal code to a modal popup created using TinyBox2 Jquery plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work when the script contains functions that will be invoked later on.

Answer (score 26):

I had this problem with innerHTML, I had to append a Hotjar script to the "head" tag of my Reactjs application and it would have to execute right after appending.

One of the good solutions for dynamic Node import into the "head" tag is [React-helment](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) module.

---

Also, there is a useful solution for the proposed issue:

**No script tags in innerHTML!**

It turns out that HTML5 does not allow script tags to be dynamically added using the innerHTML property. So the following will not execute and there will be no alert saying Hello World!

```
element.innerHTML = "<script>alert('Hello World!')</script>";
```

This is documented in the HTML5 spec:

> Note: script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when
>   they are inserted.

But beware, this doesn't mean innerHTML is safe from cross-site scripting. It is possible to execute JavaScript via innerHTML without using  tags as illustrated on [MDN's innerHTML page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

**Solution: Dynamically adding scripts**

To dynamically add a script tag, you need to create a new script element and append it to the target element.

You can do this for external scripts:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "http://www.example.com/my-script.js";
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

And inline scripts:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
newScript.appendChild(inlineScript); 
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Your `newScript` element has the [HTMLScriptElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) so you can just set the inline code with `newScript.text = "alert('Hello World!')";` no need to create and append a new text node.

Comment: @Martin
Sure, There's lots of different ways in programming world to implement stuffs!
also that's more clear and maintainable :).

Answer (score 12):

Here's a more modern (and concise) version of [mmm's awesome solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396/1343851):

```
function executeScriptElements(containerElement) {
  const scriptElements = containerElement.querySelectorAll("script");

  Array.from(scriptElements).forEach((scriptElement) => {
    const clonedElement = document.createElement("script");

    Array.from(scriptElement.attributes).forEach((attribute) => {
      clonedElement.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
    });
    
    clonedElement.text = scriptElement.text;

    scriptElement.parentNode.replaceChild(clonedElement, scriptElement);
  });
}
```

Note: I've also tried alternative solutions using [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) but that didn't work.

Comment: In my case, the added HTML contains two script tags, the first loads an external script, the second references it inline. This causes an error saying the variables exported by the external script are not defined.
If I include the two script tags directly, the code works. My guess is that the first script tag isn't completely done by the time the second is executed.

Answer (score 8):

Here a solution that does not use `eval`, and works with **scripts**, **linked scripts** , as well as with **modules**.

The function accepts 3 parameters :

- **html** : String with the html code to insert
- **dest** : reference to the target element
- **append** : boolean flag to enable appending at the end of the target element html

```
function insertHTML(html, dest, append=false){
    // if no append is requested, clear the target element
    if(!append) dest.innerHTML = '';
    // create a temporary container and insert provided HTML code
    let container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = html;
    // cache a reference to all the scripts in the container
    let scripts = container.querySelectorAll('script');
    // get all child elements and clone them in the target element
    let nodes = container.childNodes;
    for( let i=0; i< nodes.length; i++) dest.appendChild( nodes[i].cloneNode(true) );
    // force the found scripts to execute...
    for( let i=0; i< scripts.length; i++){
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = scripts[i].type || 'text/javascript';
        if( scripts[i].hasAttribute('src') ) script.src = scripts[i].src;
        script.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        document.head.removeChild(script);
    }
    // done!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I mean... Appending a script tag with code content is an eval, is it not?

Comment: @KevinB There are notorious differences ... try `eval('console.log(this)')` and you will see the most obvious one

Comment: so the context is different, and? it’s still just an eval.

Comment: @KevinB No it's not an eval. Try this `eval('let b=100')` .. and then try to access  `b` from outside the eval .... good luck with it, you are going to need it

Comment: Works for me. Cheers

Comment: wow, it does work well

Comment: this worked really nice, suggestion to add would be to be correctly wait for script onload when src and no async or defer in script attributes. I used Promises + await within loop.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it like this:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var content = "<script>alert(\"hi\");<\/script>";

mydiv.innerHTML = content;
var scripts = mydiv.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still trying to do this, no, you can't inject a script using `innerHTML`, but it is possible to load a string into a script tag using a `Blob` and `URL.createObjectURL`.

I've created an example that lets you run a string as a script and get the 'exports' of the script returned through a promise:

```
function loadScript(scriptContent, moduleId) {
    // create the script tag
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('SCRIPT');

    // create a promise which will resolve to the script's 'exports'
    // (i.e., the value returned by the script)
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        scriptElement.onload = function() {
            var exports = window["__loadScript_exports_" + moduleId];
            delete window["__loadScript_exports_" + moduleId];
            resolve(exports);
        }
    });

    // wrap the script contents to expose exports through a special property
    // the promise will access the exports this way
    var wrappedScriptContent =
        "(function() { window['__loadScript_exports_" + moduleId + "'] = " + 
        scriptContent + "})()";

    // create a blob from the wrapped script content
    var scriptBlob = new Blob([wrappedScriptContent], {type: 'text/javascript'});

    // set the id attribute
    scriptElement.id = "__loadScript_module_" + moduleId;

    // set the src attribute to the blob's object url 
    // (this is the part that makes it work)
    scriptElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(scriptBlob);

    // append the script element
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);

    // return the promise, which will resolve to the script's exports
    return promise;
}

...

function doTheThing() {
    // no evals
    loadScript('5 + 5').then(function(exports) {
         // should log 10
        console.log(exports)
    });
}
```

I've simplified this from my actual implementation, so no promises that there aren't any bugs in it. But the principle works.

If you don't care about getting any value back after the script runs, it's even easier; just leave out the `Promise` and `onload` bits. You don't even need to wrap the script or create the global `window.__load_script_exports_` property.

Comment: I just tried it and it works on chrome 57. innerHTML on a script tag executes the text.

Comment: That's interesting, it did not to work before. I wonder if this behavior is cross-browser or only in chrome 57.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a recursive function to set the innerHTML of an element that I use in our ad server:

```
// o: container to set the innerHTML
// html: html text to set.
// clear: if true, the container is cleared first (children removed)
function setHTML(o, html, clear) {
    if (clear) o.innerHTML = "";

    // Generate a parseable object with the html:
    var dv = document.createElement("div");
    dv.innerHTML = html;

    // Handle edge case where innerHTML contains no tags, just text:
    if (dv.children.length===0){ o.innerHTML = html; return; }

    for (var i = 0; i < dv.children.length; i++) {
        var c = dv.children[i];

        // n: new node with the same type as c
        var n = document.createElement(c.nodeName);

        // copy all attributes from c to n
        for (var j = 0; j < c.attributes.length; j++)
            n.setAttribute(c.attributes[j].nodeName, c.attributes[j].nodeValue);

        // If current node is a leaf, just copy the appropriate property (text or innerHTML)
        if (c.children.length == 0)
        {
            switch (c.nodeName)
            {
                case "SCRIPT":
                    if (c.text) n.text = c.text;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c.innerHTML) n.innerHTML = c.innerHTML;
                    break;
            }
        }
        // If current node has sub nodes, call itself recursively:
        else setHTML(n, c.innerHTML, false);
        o.appendChild(n);
    }
}
```

You can see the demo [here](https://jsbin.com/xuxejiveru).

Answer (score 5):

Filter your script tags and run each of them with eval

```js
var tmp=  document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = '<script>alert("hello")></script>';
[...tmp.children].filter(x => x.nodeName === 'SCRIPT').forEach(x => eval(x.innerText));
```

Comment: Simple and concise when you trust your own input. Here's my implementation: `[...document.querySelector('#content').children].filter(x => x.nodeName === 'SCRIPT').forEach(x => eval(x.innerText));`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but you have to do it outside of the DOM and the order has to be right.

```
var scr = '<scr'+'ipt>alert("foo")</scr'+'ipt>';
window.onload = function(){
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    n.innerHTML = scr;
    document.body.appendChild(n);
}
```

...will alert 'foo'. This won't work:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = scr;
```

And even this won't work, because the node is inserted first:

```
var scr = '<scr'+'ipt>alert("foo")</scr'+'ipt>';
window.onload = function(){
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(n);
    n.innerHTML = scr;  
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth: this does not appear to work on current browsers.

Answer (score 3):

My own twist, using modern JS and typescript. Not sure why people are filtering on `tagName` etc when querySelector is *right there*.

Works a charm for me:

```
function makeScriptsExecutable(el: Element) {
  el.querySelectorAll("script").forEach(script => {
    const clone = document.createElement("script")

    for (const attr of script.attributes) {
      clone.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value)
    }

    clone.text = script.innerHTML
    script.parentNode?.replaceChild(clone, script)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Krasimir Tsonev has a great solution that overcome all problems.
His method doesn't need using eval, so no performance nor security problems exist.
It allows you to set innerHTML string contains html with js and translate it immediately to an DOM element while also executes the js parts exist along the code. short ,simple, and works exactly as you want.

Enjoy his solution:

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Convert-HTML-string-to-DOM-element

Important notes:

1. You need to wrap the target element with div tag
2. You need to wrap the src string with div tag.
3. If you write the src string directly and it includes js parts, please take attention to write the closing script tags correctly (with \ before /) as this is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(parent).html(code)` instead of `parent.innerHTML = code`.

The following also fixes scripts that use `document.write` and scripts loaded via `src` attribute. Unfortunately even this doesn't work with Google AdSense scripts.

```
var oldDocumentWrite = document.write;
var oldDocumentWriteln = document.writeln;
try {
    document.write = function(code) {
        $(parent).append(code);
    }
    document.writeln = function(code) {
        document.write(code + "<br/>");
    }
    $(parent).html(html); 
} finally {
    $(window).load(function() {
        document.write = oldDocumentWrite
        document.writeln = oldDocumentWriteln
    })
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: a bit late here, but anyone that may be using this method, notice that in JQuery you need to load your scripts using $.loadScript(url) rather than <script src="url></script> - the latter will cause a deprecated Synchronous XMLHttpRequest error on browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using template and document.importNode. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="hello_world">Sample</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var div = document.createElement("div");
  var t = document.createElement('template');
  t.innerHTML =  "Check Console tab for javascript output: Hello world!!!<br/><script type='text/javascript' >console.log('Hello world!!!');<\/script>";
  
  for (var i=0; i < t.content.childNodes.length; i++){
    var node = document.importNode(t.content.childNodes[i], true);
    div.appendChild(node);
  }
 document.body.appendChild(div);
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Microsoft Edge, any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap your `<script>` like this and it will get executed:

```
<your target node>.innerHTML = '<iframe srcdoc="<script>alert(top.document.title);</script>"></iframe>';
```

Please note: The scope inside `srcdoc` refers to the iframe, so you have to use `top` like in the example above to access the parent document.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is to set a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect `<script></script>` nodes and then replace it with a new `<script></script>` node with the same src. For example:

```
let parentNode = /* node to observe */ void 0
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations=>{
    mutations.map(mutation=>{
        Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).map(node=>{
            if ( node.parentNode == parentNode ) {
                let scripts = node.getElementsByTagName('script')
                Array.from(scripts).map(script=>{
                    let src = script.src
                    script = document.createElement('script')
                    script.src = src
                    return script
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting me without saying why. Love u all.

Comment: Explanation: this snippet (added to HTML directly) ensures that any future external script added as innerHTML will be parsed. I find it as a nice universal idea, but I didn't upvote due to a concern if scripts added by `document.createElement` could be possibly executed twice? It also scares me to change the mutated object - I am not sure if it couldn't produce an infinite loop in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel Garcia's mention of MutationObservers is on the right track, but didn't quite work for me. I am not sure if that was because of a browser quirk or due to a mistake on my end, but the version that ended up working for me was the following:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(mutations=>{
        mutations.map(mutation=>{
            Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).map(node=>{
                if (node.tagName === "SCRIPT") {
                    var s = document.createElement("script");
                    s.text=node.text;
                    if (typeof(node.parentElement.added) === 'undefined')
                        node.parentElement.added = [];
                    node.parentElement.added[node.parentElement.added.length] = s;
                    node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
                    document.head.appendChild(s);
                }
            })
        })
    })
    observer.observe(document.getElementById("element_to_watch"), {childList: true, subtree: true,attributes: false});
};
```

Of course, you should replace `element_to_watch` with the name of the element that is being modified.

`node.parentElement.added` is used to store the script tags that are added to `document.head`. In the function used to load the external page, you can use something like the following to remove no longer relevant script tags:

```
function freeScripts(node){
    if (node === null)
        return;
    if (typeof(node.added) === 'object') {
        for (var script in node.added) {
            document.head.removeChild(node.added[script]);
        }
        node.added = {};
    }
    for (var child in node.children) {
        freeScripts(node.children[child]);
    }
}
```

And an example of the beginning of a load function:

```
function load(url, id, replace) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) === null) {
        console.error("Element of ID "+id + " does not exist!");
        return;
    }
    freeScripts(document.getElementById(id));
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // proceed to load in the page and modify innerHTML
}
```

Comment: You do notice that u're adding a new ``MutationObserver`` each time a element is appended to the document, right? Btw, I wonder why do you say my code is not functional.

Comment: @gabrielgarcia I said your code wasn't functional because I tried it and it simply didn't work. Looking at it now, it's entirely possible that was on me, not you, and I sincerely apologize for the way I phrased this. Fixing it now.

Comment: re: adding a MutationObserver each time an element is added to the document, what are you talking about?  DOMContentLoaded, and I quote from MDN here,"fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading." That's once, and once only. Furthermore, this script is working without issues on my site, and debugging shows it only happening once, so it's once in practice as well as in theory.

Comment: u're right... I've missridden it. My apologies aswell.

Comment: @gabrielgarcia Not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Building up on *Danny '365CSI' Engelman*'s comment, here is an universal solution:

```
<script>
  alert("This script always runs.");
  script01 = true;
</script>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
 onload="if(typeof script01==='undefined') eval(this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML)">
```

Use this as innerHTML (i.e. loaded by XMLHttpRequest) or directly (i.e. inserted by PHP backend), the script always loads once.

**Explanation**: script loaded as innerHTML is not executed, but onload content atribute is. If the script was not executed (added as innerHTML) then the script is executed in image onload event. If the script was loaded (added by backend) then `script01` variable is defined and onload will not run the script for the second time.

Comment: tnx, that was a 2016 answer. I would now do: ``<img src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'/>" onload="console.log(21,this)"/>``

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<script src="https://google.com/file.js"></script>'));
```

Comment: so the problem is, when I try to serialize HTML that contains script tags, the "<" is replaced with "\x3C" wrecking my deserializing them by assigning the serialized HTML back to an element by innerHTML.

Answer (score -1):

Execute  (Java Script) tag from innerHTML

Replace your script element with div having a class attribute class="javascript" and close it with `</div>`

Don't change the content that you want to execute (previously it was in script tag and now it is in div tag)

Add a style in your page...

`<style type="text/css"> .javascript { display: none; } </style>`

Now run  eval using jquery(Jquery js should be already included)

```
   $('.javascript').each(function() {
      eval($(this).text());

    });`
```

You can explore more [here](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.in/2013/01/execute-scripts-inside.html), at my blog.

Answer (score -1):

For me the best way is to insert the new HTML content through innerHtml and then use

```
setTimeout(() => {
        var script_el = document.createElement("script")
        script_el.src = 'script-to-add.js'
        document.body.appendChild(script_el)
    }, 500)
```

The setTimeout is not required but it works better. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

simple, no eval, no functions:

```
    fetch('/somepage')
    .then(x=>x.text())
    .then(x=>{
      divDestination.innerHTML=x;
        divDestination.querySelectorAll("script")
        .forEach(x=>{
          var sc=document.createElement("script");
          sc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x.innerText));
          divDestination.appendChild(sc)
      })      
  })
```