# How to load a js mixed in html getting from ng-route?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-routing

I used ngRoute to load html

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/route1', {
    templateUrl: '/view1',
    controller: 'controller1'
  })
  .when('/route2', {
    templateUrl: '/view2',
    controller: 'controller2'
  })
}]);
```

When I switch to `route1`, I get html like this:

```
<div>
  bla bla bla ...
</div>
<script src="js1.js"></script>
```

Then how to load `js1.js` after getting html successfully?

Comment: could you please explain it clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate: [execute-javascript-loaded-via-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021095/execute-javascript-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: Sorry for my wrong description. I've edited my question.

Comment: If the problem still is loading javascript dynamically with ajax, then it is the same issue did you see watch the link? maybe this is easier: [how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block)

Comment: er...I don't know where to put codes to run `eval`, because `ng-route` encapsuled the ajax work.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is an old question, but I had the same problem and, searching on Google, I've solved.
You can use this (with jQuery): `$.getScript("js1.js", function(){});` in your controller1, like this:

```
app.controller('controller1', function(/*parameters you need*/){
  /*your controller code*/
  $.getScript("js1.js", function(){});
});
```

You can see other about `$.getScript` here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

and in your template1 don't put js.