# Dynamically adding script to a div does not execute the script

Tags: javascript

**PROBLEM:**

Why does this not show the alert? And how can I make it so?

```
<script>
    function onSuccess() {
        var response= "<script> alert(1);</\script>";
        document.getElementById("xxx").innerHTML = response;
    }
</script>
<div id="xxx">existing text</div>
<button id="click" onclick="onSuccess();">click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hWRR/1/

This is just a simplified version of my problem. In our application *(in one very old module in particular)* we use an ancient home-grown AJAX class which just `innerHTMLs` all AJAX responses.Traditionally we have only sent back HTML as AJAX response but I would like to execute JS in the success handler.I do not have access to the JS file so cannot modify the way the response is handled. I can only work with the fact that the success handler calls `div.innerHTML='<my response>'`

So stupid as it may be, I'm hoping for some help using these constraints!

**SIMILAR LINKS:**

[Dynamically adding script element to a div does not execute the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567312/dynamically-adding-script-element-to-a-div-does-not-execute-the-script)

[Dynamically added script will not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761149/dynamically-added-script-will-not-execute)

Comment: I think sometimes is worth going through the social trouble to get that JS file than to fix a broken system.

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery? Its `.load()` method scans the returned HTML for `<script>` tags and arranges for them to be executed. Doing it yourself will be a PITA.

Comment: If you can't change the fact that the handler just sets `.innerHTML` then you're SOL. That mechanism will simply never execute a script, it's not how it works. Wasn't that clear from the questions you linked to?

Comment: Is the div always the same?

Comment: @Barmar I knew about jQuery load() but unfortunately we cant use it. And yes it seemed pretty clear that innerHTML cant execute scripts, but was hoping against hope! Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: Here I'm assuming the `<div>` on which the results are inserted is known.

A possible solution is to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (and the [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) event, to support IE 9 and 10) to watch said `<div>` for changes on its contents, and execute the code on any inserted `<script>` tags.

Example built upon your jsFiddle:

```
watchNodeForScripts(document.getElementById("xxx"));

function watchNodeForScripts(scriptRecipient) {
  if ('MutationObserver' in window) {
    // Prefer MutationObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
    watchUsingMutationObserver();
  } else {
    // Fallback to Mutation Events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events
    watchUsingDeprecatedMutationEvents();
  }

  function watchUsingMutationObserver() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var i, addedNodes = mutation.addedNodes;

        for (i = 0; i < addedNodes.length; i++) {
          handleAddedNode(addedNodes[i]);
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(scriptRecipient, {
      childList: true
    });
  }

  function watchUsingDeprecatedMutationEvents() {
    scriptRecipient.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) {
      handleAddedNode(event.target);
    });
  }

  function handleAddedNode(node) {
    // Don't try to execute non-script elements
    if (!(node instanceof HTMLScriptElement)) return;

    // Don't try to execute linked scripts
    if (node.src !== "") return;

    // Use 'new Function' instead of eval to avoid
    // the creation of a (undesired) closure
    fn = new Function(node.textContent);
    fn.call(window);
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hWRR/13/

**Edit**: Changed `innerText` to the more cross-compatible [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

**Edit2**: Don't execute code that isn't inside a `<script>` element.

**Edit3**: Don't execute scripts with the `src` attribute, and add mutation events fallback

Comment: That's a pretty cool way of doing it,I had never heard of MutationObserver before, read up on it now..This example didnt work on chrome for me though.. No error ,just didnt show the alert.

Comment: Weird, I use chrome and it executed just fine for me... Which version are you on?

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I've just made a change. Can you test it out again?

Comment: worked, perfect! also thanks for the informative edit comment.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar great :) Just be sure to take a look at [MutationEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) too, because you will need to fallback to them if you need to support IE < 11. MutationObserver is a relatively new API, and no IE before 11 has it.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I don't know if you get notifications for edited answers, so I'm pinging you: I've made some changes to support IE 9 and 10, you might want to check it out.

Comment: that's fantastic..I was wondering why u were using new Function() instead of eval(), i get it now after seeing ur comment.Also love the way u've thought of linked scripts (though i cant believe someone would append a JS file reference to an Element,well, unless its the head ur watching).. very cool code man.. i would double accept it if I could :( !