# ajax loading php with facebook-Java not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some code on a main page (index.php) that calls a php script (access.php) with javascript, as seen below.
The php (access.php) also has javascript but when I load it into the current page (index.php) then the javascript content in (access.php) is not working. Maybe this can't be done. Any thoughts?

The javascript does fire when I load access.php in a browser by itself.

```
$.post("access.php",
              {FullName : response.name,ID: response.id,Email:response.email,UD:userDevice},

          function(data) 
          {
           document.getElementById('Container').innerHTML = data;
         });
```

Perhaps I should have stated this before but it's using the Facebook Java SDK. MY END GOAL: I want to SEND VARS to a php that also has more/new Facebook-Java script that I can run from within the index.php.

Comment: Dynamically loaded Javascript is loaded, but not executed.  Check out this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block

Comment: it's not tagged as jQuery but I can see you are using jQuery so please look at `load` method. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: What kind of javascript would you like to run on the access.php site?

Comment: Actually I have complicated matters. The access file actually adds an "include with php". It loads a mobile site or a desktop site. Both sites have jquery in it that I wish to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method worked. :)

```
$( "#Container" ).load( "access.php", 
{FullName : response.name,ID: response.id,
Email:response.email,UD:userDevice} );
```