# My Javascript Source Not Included When Open Modal With Content From Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

I have some modal in index.php and want to load content into my modal with ajax request to ajax.php.
when i try to load the content with `ajax.php` the response `inner ajax.php` has load normaly but my `.js` in `index.php` not load for example my datepicker is not loaded inside modals

Call Function :

AJAX Request :

```
<script>
        function addProduct(str) {
            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("responseModal").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("responseModal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","SERVER/ajax.php?id="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

My Modal:

```
            <div class="xx-modal" id="open-modal">
                <div class="xx-modal-dialog">
                    <button class="xx-modal-close uk-close" type="button"></button>
                    <div id="responseModal">Waiting For AJAX to Load!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And This My JavaScript Src that i want to included inside my modal

```
    <script src="example.com/static/assets/js/xxxx.js"></script>
    <script src="example.com/static/assets/js/xxxx.js"></script>
    <script src="example.com/static/assets/js/xxxx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically added javascript with external script doesn't get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476544/dynamically-added-javascript-with-external-script-doesnt-get-executed)

Comment: i've tried but not work, but i've solved my case thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("responseModal").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
       }
```

You problems is **THIS** *this.responseText*