# Execution of dynamically generated Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, properties, innerhtml

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block) question with the accepted answer being:

> Script added by setting the innerHTML property of an element doesn't get executed.

But when I try to change the innerHTML of the first `<script>` tag in the following code:

```
<script></script>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("script")[0].innerHTML = 'console.log("Test")';
</script>
```

I can see the injected code for the `<script>` element being executed (the `console.log()` function outputs Test).

Furthermore if I remove the first empty `<script>` tag (thus making the first element `[0]`  refer to the script itself), the script is changed in the DOM, but the code is never executed.

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("script")[0].innerHTML = 'console.log("Test")';
</script>
```

What prompts this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in [Scripting](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scripting-1). When the script is being [prepared](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script),

1. At step 2, the "parser-inserted" flag is removed:

   > If the element has its ["parser-inserted"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted) flag set, then set
   >   *was-parser-inserted* to true and unset the element's ["parser-inserted"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted) flag.
2. At step 4, before restoring the "parser-inserted" flag, the steps are aborted

   > If the element has no [`src`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute, and its child nodes, if
   >   any, consist only of comment nodes and empty [`Text`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#text-0) nodes, then
   >   the user agent must abort these steps at this point. The script is not
   >   executed.

Therefore, when you modify it, it will be prepared again:

> When a [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element that is not marked as being
>   ["parser-inserted"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#parser-inserted) experiences one of the events listed in the
>   following list, the user agent must synchronously [prepare](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script) the
>   [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element:
>
> - The [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element gets [inserted into a document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#insert-an-element-into-a-document), at the time the [node is inserted](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#nodes-are-inserted) according to the DOM, after any
>     other [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) elements inserted at the same time that are
>     earlier in the [`Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) in [tree order](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree-order).
> - The [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element is [in a `Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#in-a-document) and a node or document fragment is [inserted](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#nodes-are-inserted) into the [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element,
>     after any [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) elements [inserted](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#nodes-are-inserted) at that time.
> - The [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element is [in a `Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#in-a-document) and has a [`src`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute set where previously the element had no such
>     attribute.

Once the script ran, modifying the contents won't execute them, because script preparation will abort:

> If the [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element is marked as having ["already
>   started"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#already-started), then the user agent must abort these steps at this
>   point. The script is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting finding indeed!

It really seems that empty src-less `script` element is in some strange state that accepts either content or even new `src` and interprets them.  (Couldn't find a reason for that either. I just have a tiny hint: )

**It *resembles* behavior of dynamically inserted script elements.**

Here is example/proof of your observation and added few more cases for illustration:

```css
script[src]::before,
script {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}
script[src]::before,
script {
  content: 'src='attr(src)
}
button {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<p>Existing empty script in HTML:</p>
<script id="existing"></script>
<p>Can be invoked just one of:</p>
<button onclick="eval(this.innerText)">
  existing.innerHTML='console.log("innerHTML to static")'
</button>
<button onclick="eval(this.innerText)">
  existing.src='data:text/javascript,console.log("src to static")'
</button>
<p>Dynamically created and inserted script (each creates own, so both work):</p>
<button onclick="eval(this.innerText)">
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).innerHTML='console.log("innerHTML to dynamic")'
</button>
<button onclick="eval(this.innerText)">
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='data:text/javascript,console.log("src to dynamic")'
</button>
```

You will have to re-run snippet to see both "static" cases works.

(Also there is a blank script containing white-space generated by SO, for whatever reason.)

As Laurianti demonstrated, if the script had some (even white-space) content (or `src=""`), it would not work.

Also, in the "dynamic" examples notice that the `innerHTML` or `src` value is altered **after** the `script` element had been inserted to the document.  So it is possible to have a blank static or create dynamic script, leave it in the document and set use it long after that.

Sorry for not giving a full answer, just wanted to share research and the hint.

---

(Update removed; Oriol was faster and way more accurate. Phew, glad to see this sorted out!)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the innerHTML, it will not executed. You have to write it before and after you have to append it.

```js
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.innerHTML = 'console.log("Test");';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Try to adding a new line:

```
<script>
</script>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("script")[0].innerHTML = 'console.log("Test")';
</script>
```

Comment: But when I change the innerHTML my script is getting executed, which is the entire point of my question - why is this happening?

Comment: Because it's empty. I don't know the why.

Comment: Because you are writing a self executing line of code instead of a variable or function that has to called separately.