# jQuery doesn't work with pages loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have seen other questions like this one here but they didn't seem to help.

I have purchased an html theme that changes/transitions between pages with ajax.

When I slide into a certain page where I am trying to use jQuery, nothing happens. But if I refresh that page then the jQuery fires.

Is there a way to get the jquery to work when transitioning into the page instead of having to refresh it?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what exactly you're trying to achieve and show some codes?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with dynamically created elements that do not exist within the DOM.

Comment: Do you have an example?  Code "works" in that it does exactly what it's told to do.  What is this code being told to do?  What isn't it doing?  "How do I get jQuery to work" isn't an answerable question.  It *is* working, it just sounds like you want it to do something other than what it's written to do.  Provide a specific example of the problem.

Comment: @AdamA, do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: @David, at this point I am just trying to console.log a message: `$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("working");
  
 });`

Comment: So the JavaScript itself is being loaded into the page dynamically and not executing?  Perhaps this would be helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block

Comment: Would it help if I gave you a link to the theme so you can see what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your template is set up but move jQuery to whatever the base file is that loads other libraries. It should be where all the CSS, etc, is loaded also.

Comment: I managed to get it to work like this: `$(document).on('click', "#submit", function () {` but I can only submit the form once. If there are validation errors and I try again, nothing happens

Comment: Try putting that in another question with code examples.