# script doesn't load after ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I was trying to make an ajax call and show an html part inside a div class. For that i used the following way.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{url('searchByCheckbox')}}",
    dataType: 'html',
      success: function(html)
        {
           $(".infinite-scroll").html(html)
        }   
});
```

But the problem is there is a script inside that html part which i wanted to load when i make first ajax call it's not loaded but for the second one it's loaded the script.
 suppose the html response like this :

```
<script>
  alert()
</script>
// html
```

How do i make it work? 
I put the script above the html page which i'm getting as response.

(those who are marking the Question as duplicate should read at least what i want and what they wanted )

Comment: Did you try `$(".infinite-scroll").text(html)` ?

Comment: @ricky, that will display the HTML as plain text.

Comment: Do you get your HTML request? As far as I understand you get response but `script` inside you response HTML doesn't work, am I right?

Comment: @OP What you observe is default behavior; if you want to run code loaded via AJAX, you have to call it yourself. A better solution is to restructure your website so all code is in the main document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you execute a dynamically loaded JavaScript block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block)

Comment: @ricky that'll show the html as text inside that div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)

Comment: What is the ajax result can you share with us?

Comment: ajax result would be a foreach loop inside a div

Answer (score 0):

Im sure that the error is happening because of the script, because you are closing the `</script>` tag inside the html.

The best solution is to return the data from your `ajax` call as a `json`

To do that you should:

1- add a `dataType` to your `ajax` parameter as the below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
```

2- In the `php` file handling the `ajax` call, you must resurn the values as a json as below:

Assume that currently you are doing the following:

```
echo $html
```

You should change it to match the below:

```
$retArr = array(
    "html"     => $html, //Your html code without the javascript function
    "jsFunc"   => $jsFunc //Your java script function parameters
) ;
echo json_encode($retArr) ;
```

And then your `ajax success` must be as the below:

```
success: function(data)
    { //You can access all the object parametes by calling the object name `data` followed by a dot `.` and then by the parameter key
       data.jsFunc // Your javascript function params
       $(".infinite-scroll").html(data.html) ;
    }
```