# How can I rewrite the document and execute the script in it without rerefreshing it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files:

`a.html`

```html
...
<script>
var foo = 1;  // and some initialization
// load b.html
</script>
...
```

`b.html`

```html
...
<head>
  <!-- may contains external resources -->
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is b.html</p>
</body>
<script>
window.alert(foo);  // but I want to use the `foo` variable
</script>
...
```

I don't care if the elements and scripts in `a.html` works, but I want all the elements and scripts in `b.html` to work just as they would if I opened it in a separate window. I also want to keep some environment variables in `a.html`, such as `foo`.

I tried `document.getElementByTagName('html').outerHTML = xxx`, but the script in `b.html` has not been executed.

I tried `window.location.href = "b.html"`, but the entire page is refreshed and I can't get the value of `foo`.

I tried "[ajax - How do you execute a dynamically loaded JavaScript block? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943/how-do-you-execute-a-dynamically-loaded-javascript-block)", but the answer which have the highest score doesn't work in my browser. I also can't find a way to rewrite the `html` tag. I also don't know if this solution can load external resources.

Is there any other way without editing `b.html`?

Comment: I don't think it is even possible

Answer (score 2):

Append `a.html` to `b.html` in an `iframe`. You can then establish communation between the frames using `parent.postMessage()` from `a.html` to `b.html`, including posting the variable `foo` from the embedded frame to the parent frame.

Comment: Can I move the contents of the iframe to root and still keep `b.html` running correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by _"move the contents of the iframe"_? You can post messages and transfer transferable objects from the `iframe` to the `parent` frame and vice versa.

Comment: @Zxd2009 Are you trying to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/33649349#33649349 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session/36146764#36146764 ?